# Why doesn't the bid/ask reflect my ask price on a spread options position I am trying to get rid of?

Tags: stocks, options, spreads, bid-ask

[image]

I entered this trade in about a week ago. It's always been under the ask but the ask never reflects my ask.  Why?

Comment: What does your broker say?

Comment: Ask your broker why your price doesn't update the quote.  With a B/A spread that wide, for trades at the market, the spread must rise 25% to break even.  You had better hope that you don't have to close your spread early.  You'll pay dearly to get out if it remains that wide.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your broker to be sure, and I'm assuming you're talking about a compound "spread" option like a calendar spread, not an option ON a spread, but in my (limited) experience, the published "ask" for a spread is just a combination of the component options, so the fact that you put in a limit order at $30 does not change the bid or ask of the underlying options. Your broker *should* execute your order once the spread goes to 30 or below, but since your order does not change the bid/ask of the component options, it is not reflected in the quoted "ask" of the spread.

As an example, suppose you're long a straddle (long call and long put) and the current quotes are:

```
       Bid   Ask
Call  12.00 16.00
Put   12.80 16.70
```

The "bid" of this spread trade would be 24.80 (that's what it would cost you to buy the spread), and the "ask" would be 32.70. Since you put in a sell order for the *spread* and not the individual options, the bid and ask of the options does not change, hence the ask of the spread does not change.

If, instead, you put in sell orders under the ask for the component options, then you *would* see that in the quote of the spread, but then your options would be sold individually, which is probably not what you want.